# When is $\cos (x) \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

When is $\cos (x) \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

I know the function repeats, so I know I should end up with an interval that allows for integer multiples.

e.g. something like this (but obviously not this exactly) $[0 + n, \pi + n]$.

Comment: Do you know when $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Draw a circle of radius $r=1$ and vertical line through $x=0.5$. Then draw the usual triangle used to define $\cos$ and arrive at some conclusion (later you can use the symmetry properties of $\cos$).

Comment: $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ when $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @user174606 and when $x = -\frac{\pi}{3}$, if I'm not mistaken. Is that enough to see what intervals you are looking for?

Comment: Suppose that you have an equilateral triangle where the height has been penciled in. This creates 2 right angled triangles (one to the left of the height, and one to the right). If a side of the equilateral triangle is 2, what is the length of the base of one of the $half$ triangles? Actually draw the picture.

Answer (score 4):

First, we solve $\cos x=\frac12$, which is for $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $x=\frac{5\pi}{3}$.

Then, we take a look at the unit circle.

[image]

The cosine value is the $x$-coordinate, so the question we ask is: "for which $x$ is the $x$-coordinate greater than or equal to $\frac12$?".

In the first quadrant, we have $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $[0,\frac{\pi}{3}]$.
In the fourth quadrant, we have $\frac{5\pi}{3}\leq x\leq2\pi$ or $[\frac{5\pi}{3},2\pi]$.

Now, we add the periodicity. We now that $\cos(x)=\cos(x+2\pi)$, so we can always add $+2\pi$ to our answer.

Therefore, the final answer is:

$\cos(x)\geq\frac12$ for $x\in[2\pi n,\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n]\cup[\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\pi n,2\pi+2\pi n]$ or, preferably for some, $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n, \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n]$, ($n\in\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: This makes it look like there are two separate repeating intervals, but actually they come in pairs of subintervals that meet at a multiple of $2\pi.$ So this may be the most thorough and accessible explanation but I prefer the answers that come out to just one interval plus its repetitions.

Comment: @David K, I also added the one interval notation. +1 now? ;-)

Comment: Since the one interval was my only complaint I guess I have no alternative now, do I? :-)

Answer (score 2):

$[-\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n, \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\pi n]$

On $[-\pi, \pi], \cos(x) > 1/2 \quad \iff \quad x\in[-\pi/3, \pi/3]$

Indeed, $\cos(\pi/3) = 1/2$, and you know that cosine is an even function.

Moreover, cosine is $2\pi$-periodic, and therefore have you can translate $[-\pi/3, \pi/3]$ by $2\pi n, n\in \mathbb{N}$ to get all possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- For what values of $x$ is the $x$ component of a point on the unit circle at least $1/2$?  (Drawing this may help.)
- You know the function repeats.  How much do you add to the angle to go once around the circle?
- How do you express this amount so that you can go around twice, three times, $n$ times?  How about going around in the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

Counting the angles in turns ($360°$), and looking at the plot of the $\cos$ function ($\cos(\pm60°)=\frac12$), the intervals are $$[-\frac16+n,\frac16+n].$$

[image]